# How to statically apply a function to individual elements of a non-type template pack and sum the results?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

Is there a better way more compact to implement the computation of *nBits* below at compile time? Please note that the question is not how to implement *n_active_bits*, which I know how to do.

```
constexpr int n_active_bits(int m) { /* count the bits */ }

template <uint8_t...Masks>
struct MaskPack
{
    // is there a more concise way than to implement 
    //the auxiliary recursive function count_bits?
    static constexpr uint8_t nBits = count_bits(Masks...);
private:
    template <typename M, typename...Ms>
    static constexpr uint8_t count_bits(M&& m, Ms&&...ms)
    {
            return n_active_bits(m) + count_bits(ms...);
    }
    static constexpr uint8_t count_bits()
    {
            return 0;
    }
};
```

I tried with no luck to use the one-liner C++17 folds:

```
static constexpr uint8_t nBits = (n_active_bits(Masks) + ...);
```

Comment: `n_active_bits` must surely be constexpr as well...

Comment: Yes, it is constexpr (I updated the question). Perhaps it is my gcc which is not new enough...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It requires some boilerplate.

```
template<size_t I, class Indexes>
struct offset_indexes;
template<size_t I, class Indexes>
using offset_indexes_t = typename offset_indexes<I,Indexes>::type;
template<size_t I, size_t...Is>
struct offset_indexes<I, std::index_sequence<Is...>> {
  using type=std::index_sequence<(I+Is)...>;
};
```

then a binary fold:

```
template<size_t...Is, class Tuple>
constexpr auto retuple( std::index_sequence<Is...>, Tuple&& tuple ) {
  return std::forward_as_tuple( std::get<Is>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple))... );
}
template<class F, class T>
constexpr T binary_fold( F&& f, std::tuple<T>&& tuple ) {
  return std::get<0>(std::move(tuple));
}
template<class Tuple>
struct first_element {};
template<class Tuple>
using first_element_t=typename first_element<Tuple>::type;
template<template<class...>class Z, class T0, class...Ts>
struct first_element<Z<T0,Ts...>>{using type=T0;};

template<class F, class Tuple, class E=first_element_t<std::decay_t<Tuple>>>
constexpr std::decay_t<E> binary_fold( F&& f, Tuple&& tuple ) {
  constexpr auto count = std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<Tuple>>{};
  using first_half = std::make_index_sequence< count/2 >;
  using second_half = offset_indexes_t<
    count/2,
    std::make_index_sequence< (count+1)/2 >
  >;

  return f(
    binary_fold( f, retuple( first_half{},  std::forward<Tuple>(tuple) ) ),
    binary_fold( f, retuple( second_half{}, std::forward<Tuple>(tuple) ) )
  );
}
```

which should make a binary tree of recursive calls to `binary_fold`.

All of this makes `count_bits` easy:

```
template <class...Ms>
constexpr size_t count_bits(Ms&&...ms)
{
  return binary_fold(
    std::plus<>{},
    std::make_tuple(n_active_bits(std::forward<Ms>(ms))...)
  );
}
```

note, however, that there is lots of boilerplate.

I did a more complex binary fold, because left/right fold has a deep recursive depth.

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c54f72de2a721642).

Comment: Wow. That's fold without compiler support. Interesting.

Answer (score 4):

With folds you can do it as follows:

```
template <uint8_t...Masks>
struct MaskPack {
   static constexpr uint8_t nBits = (n_active_bits(Masks) + ...);
};
```

[**Live Demo**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/k8486ZVWCL1Zz1zp)

Note that `n_active_bits` must be `constexpr`:

```
constexpr int n_active_bits(unsigned int mask) {
  return mask == 0 ? 0 : (mask & 0x01) + n_active_bits(mask >> 1);
}
```